# Frobenius map on certain elements

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, modular-arithmetic

I would appreciate some help with understanding the following setup:

Let $a\in \mathbb{F}_q$ is a primitive root of unity with $q=3^d$. Consider a rational function $f(x) \in \mathbb{F}_3(x)$, where $f(x)=x^{-q+3}+x+x^{-1}+x^{q-3} +2x^{2q-1}+2x^{1-2q}$. Suppose one suspects that $f(a)\not\in \mathbb{F}_3 $, how can one go about showing this?

My attempt was to notice that the map $F:y \mapsto y^3 $ fixes $\mathbb{F}_3$-points and if one can show that $f(a) \neq (f(a))^3$ then we got our result. Thus, can one try to use the following?
$$(x^{-q+3}+x+x^{-1}+x^{q-3} +2x^{2q-1}+2x^{1-2q})^3= x^{-3q+9}+x+x^{-3}+x^{3q-9} +2x^{6q-3}+2x^{3-9q}$$

But I'm not sure how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated.

$\textbf{One more question:}$

Also, is it true that over $\mathbb{F}_3$ we have $(x^t + y^{2t}+2z^{t-1})^3= x^{3t} + y^{6t}+ 2z^{3t-3}$?

Comment: For your last question, $(x^t + y^{2t}+2z^{t-1})^3=(x^t + y^{2t})^3+(2z^{t-1})^3=x^{3t}+y^{6t}+8z^{3t-3}=x^{3t}+y^{6t}+2z^{3t-3}$, since in a field $k$ of char $p\neq0$, $(a+b)^p=a^p+b^p$.